# How to build apk in ionic 3 if keystore value is already generated

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, apk

I tried to take the release build in ionic 3 that already built the apk file with the key store and was uploaded in the play store.

Now I have made some changes in my code and I need to generate an apk and need to upload it to the play store with same JKS file.

Actually I need to update the next version of my app. How do I take the build in that same file?

When I run it shows:

```
Enter keystore password:  
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Key pair not generated, alias <my-alias> already exists
java.lang.Exception: Key pair not generated, alias <my-alias> already exists
    at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doGenKeyPair(Main.java:1721)
    at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:1007)
    at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:366)
    at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:359)
```

Comment: What are you actually doing? Can you show us the commands you are using to sign your APK?

Comment: You probably need to create a new build number if you're upadting your app. Just make sure to update the app version in your config.xml and package.json file.